# What does "The Hercules play comes in there" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does "The Hercules play comes in there" mean?

On April 8, 1907, the alleged spirit of Myers, through Mrs. Piper, said to
Mrs. Sidgwick:
"Do you remember Euripides? Do you remember Spirit and Angel? I gave
both... Nearly all the words I have written to-day are with reference to
messages I am trying to give through Mrs. V."
Mrs. Verrall had, on March 7, in the course of an automatic script, the
words "Hercules Furens" and "Euripides." And on March 25 Mrs.
Verrall had written:
**The Hercules play comes in there** and the clue is in the Euripides play, if
you could only see it...
This certainly seems beyond coincidence.

" The History of Spiritualism," by Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herakles_(Euripides)): *Herakles (Ancient Greek: Ἡρακλῆς μαινόμενος, Hēraklēs Mainomenos, also known as **Hercules Furens**) is an Athenian tragedy **by Euripides** that was first performed c. 416 BC.* Don't ask me why Mrs Verrall seems to be referring to *Hercules Furens* and "the Euripides play" as two different things.

Answer (score 3):

It means, "The play about Hercules becomes relevant the discussion at this point."

The phrase "[noun] comes into it" in English is a way of saying you're introducing an element that has previously been unimportant but is now important or relevant to what you're talking about. For example, "This is where the police came into it" would mean "This is the point in the story where the police became important to the events".